# assetic:dump command not dumping images

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

As far as I know, the command `php app/console assetic:dump` should take everything from `app/Resources/public`, process it if necessary (say Sass file -> CSS file), and dump it into the `web/` folder. When I run the command, my javascript files and css files get transferred correctly, however, my images do not. They do not get transferred to `web/` at all. How can I get the images to transfer from my non-public directory to the public one on assetic:dump?

My file structure:

```
+-symfony/
  +-app/
    +-Resources/
      +-public/
        +-css/
          //All of my CSS files
        +-javascripts/
          //All of my JS files
        +-images/
          //All of my image assets
```

My layout file looks like so:

```
{% stylesheets
  'css/bootstrap_loader.css.scss'
  'css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'
  'css/style.css.scss'
  'css/learners.css'
  'css/stately/*'
  filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts
  'js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
  '@bootstrap_js'
  'js/landing_page.js'
  'js/homepage_video.js'
  '//use.typekit.net/rah2apm.js'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong. `Assetic` is not the same as `assets`.

`Assetic` is a library that can compile your JS or CSS with some filters.

Assets is your resources.

Try to run:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

It will create symlink folder inside `web/` directory that will point to your bundle's `Resources/public` folder.

If you omit `--symlink` option it will hard copy all your assets once and you will need to run this command every time you changed your assets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I ran this command and the output was: ```Installing assets using the symlink option
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
```
This seems like it skipped my assets which are stored in ```%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/images```. My assets are not stored in a separate bundle, just the default AppBundle Symfony ships with.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't catch sight of your directory structure. If you use this way to store resources (global for whole application) you should store it in the `web/` dir.

Comment: So just so I'm absolutely sure, I should just place the images directly in the ```web/``` dir? Will this prevent any cache busting on images?

Comment: About what cache busting are you talking?

Comment: When I run ```assetic:dump``` Assetic takes my css/js files, processes them, and changes their name. For instance, ```style.css``` will be processed and placed into ```web/``` with a new name of ```1e61613.css```. This is useful for cache-busting old versions of the file that may be cached in the browser. Presumably if I run the images through Assetic, I could get the cache-busting feature applied to my images, so if I change the image but keep the same filename, such as ```masthead-4.jpg```, I will know the new image is displayed because assetic will have changed the name to a unique value.

Comment: I just think it would be useful to have this feature applied to images as well as css/js assets. If this is not how Symfony is supposed to work, then I can live with putting the images in web/

Comment: Your css and js files will be with the same name after updating. You need to configure version for them manually. And images will be processed only if you have some assetic filter to process them. In your case you should place your images in `web/` dir and manually manage them.